# My ArrayAdapter gives me null value - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to display my sqlite data in textview with kotlin android app. But i have an error with this. When i run my app, it breaks. What is the problem?

Here is my read_data function in dbhelper:

```
fun read_data():MutableList<Kullanici> {
    val userList:MutableList<Kullanici> = ArrayList()
    val db = this.readableDatabase
    val query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name"

    val result = db.rawQuery(query,null)
    if(result.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            val kullanici = Kullanici()
            kullanici.id = result.getString(result.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column_id)).toInt()
            kullanici.hamle = result.getString(result.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column_hamle)).toInt()
            kullanici.sure = result.getString(result.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column_sure)).toInt()
            userList.add(kullanici)

        }while (result.moveToNext())
    }

    result.close()
    db.close()
    return userList

}
```

And here is my main acitivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    val lv = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
    val db  = DataBaseHelper(this)

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    supportActionBar?.hide()
    val kolay_butonu = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
    kolay_butonu.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, Kolay::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


    val liste = db.read_data()
    val adapter_: ArrayAdapter<*>
    adapter_ = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste)
    lv.adapter = adapter_

}
```

and finally the error i encountered:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should call `findViewById` after `setContentView`. The view is only inflated when `setContentView` is called, so when you find view before `setContentView` is called, it will return null.

just move this line

```
val lv = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
```

after `setContentView`

Comment: oh, its really worked. But i need another problem now. I cant see my data correctly. I have an integer values at table. But in listview data is com.example.mobil_odev.Kullanici@blabla

should i need to use .text() at somewhere? I am new in Kotlin sorry about this

Comment: i think it is because you use basic array adapter, which is supposed to be used for list of string only, and when the object is not string, it will convert it with `toString` method. In your case however, you have list of `Kullanici` object. You can either map your list to list of string that you want to show, or make custom adapter to process your list ob `Kullanici`

Comment: to give clear example, if you want to show the property `hamle`, you can create a new list with `val newList = liste.map { it.hamle.toString() }` and set the adapter as `adapter_ = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newList)`

Comment: its really worked, omg. I can't thank you enough...

Comment: glad to help. :)
can you mark my answer as the accepted answer please? thank you.

Comment: of course, i did